# How do I send only the form values to email?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**My problem:**

When I run the project, I'm getting the email twice, once with just the labels like below:

```
Student ID: 
Student Name:
Student Age:

Student Major:
StudentGPA:
```

And another with actual values I give in the form and submit. Like below:

```
Student ID: 90
Student Name:zx
Student Age:24

Student Major:2
StudentGPA:3.4
```

**How do I stop the label being emailed to me?**

Below is my code if you'd like to see. Thanks!

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult AddStudentInfo(Models.StudentRecord Stu)
{


    List<SelectListItem> paitems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    SelectListItem item1 = new SelectListItem() { Text = "A", Value = "1", Selected = true };
    SelectListItem item2 = new SelectListItem() { Text = "R", Value = "2", Selected = false };
    SelectListItem item3 = new SelectListItem() { Text = "D Plates", Value = "3", Selected = false };

    paitems.Add(item1);
    paitems.Add(item2);
    paitems.Add(item3);
    ViewBag.StudentMajor = paitems;


    string body = "Student ID: " + Stu.studentID + "\n"
                        + "Student Name:" + Stu.studentName + "\n"
                        + "Student Age:" + Stu.studentAge + "\n\n"
                        + "Student Major:" + Stu.studentMajor + "\n"
                        +"StudentGPA:" + Stu.studentGPA + "\n\n";
    MailMessage mailBody = new MailMessage("mmtest@gmail.com","test1@gmail.com");
    mailBody.Subject = "Contact Form";
    mailBody.Body = body;

    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
    smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test1", "test123!");

    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    smtpClient.Send(mailBody);


    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        connection();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("InsertData", conn);
        com.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentID", Stu.studentID);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentName", Stu.studentName);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentAge", Stu.studentAge);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentMajor", Stu.studentMajor);

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentGPA", Stu.studentGPA);
        conn.Open();

        int i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        if (i>=1)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "New Student has been added";

        }

    }
    ModelState.Clear();
    return View();
}
```

**View**

I guess there's nothing much to do with the view. I have all those attributes there. But, here is just the submit button:

```
<script>
    function myAlert() {
        window.confirm("Student added successfully");
    }
</script>

<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
    <input type="submit" value="Add" onclick="myAlert()" class="btn btn-default" />
</div>
```

**Model**

```
[Display(Name = "Student ID")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Student ID")]
public string studentID { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Student Name")]
public string studentName { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Student Age")]
public string studentAge { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Student Major")]
public string studentMajor { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Student GPA")]
public string studentGPA { get; set; }
```

Comment: You may want to only send the email after you've confirmed the ModelState is valid. What's the `myAlert()` function look like?

Comment: Hey Jonathan, it's just a window alert. I've updated my code by adding the myAlert() function. Thanks

Comment: Jonathan, it worked. I'll wait for some more time and see if it is being sent twice. For now, I'm getting only the form values after I submit the form. Thanks man!

Comment: Since the `confirm` dialog returns a boolean, you should adjust your `myAlert()` function to be `return window.confirm('Are you sure?');` (or whatever confirmation message works for you) and the `onclick` event should be changed up to `onclick="return myAlert()"`. This way your user can cancel the submission with the confirmation dialog.

Comment: Tommy, I understand. I'll try to implement this in my code. However, I implemented what Jonathan suggested and it works fine. Many thanks to you for your suggestion.

Comment: Good deal - and its an AJAX post as well which would change the flavor of my comment.  Good luck to you, glad you got it to work!